# Novel cob pebble

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> Once raided by someone who sounds like five hundred,
>   or something that crashed on Armenian highlands,
>   like luminous city's triumphant landmark,
>   a 40's gun disjoined by queen saying "aah".
>
> Iberian grapes go through long fermenation,
>   adapted in order to run on some system,
>   so take a look north as the ship's sailing east,
>   divide place in German by one million squared.
>
> A novel cob pebble a famous example,
>   a punishment giver or crime-fighting writer,
>   remember: use one hand and start with the king,
>   a system of status with fifty between.
>
> A paradise minus an Edmonton constant,
>   a place to escape one's finance obligations,
>   a shelter for ships made all safe and secure,
>   a home theater system surrounded by fowl.

What do we have in common?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Third Verse

> **CASTLE**

A novel cob pebble a famous example,

> Neuschwanstein Castle, which is German for "new swan stone"

a punishment giver or crime-fighting writer,

> The TV show *Castle* features a crime-fighting writer; not sure about punishment giver

remember: use one hand and start with the king,

> "castle" is a chess move. you're supposed to move the king first, and use the same hand to move the rook afterwards.

a system of status with fifty between.

> cast-L-e

**FINAL ANSWER**

> The four answers are:
>  Ark (@KateGregory)
>  Port (@oryxandcake)
>  Castle 
>  Haven (@WeatherVane)
>  These can all be preceded by "New" to form cities in New England:
>  Newark (NJ), Newport (RI), Newcastle (ME), New Haven (CT)

Comment: Not sure if you're a fan of comics but rot13(Chavfure'f erny anzr vf Senax Pnfgyr)

Comment: This is the intended answer. The tick will follow tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

Last verse:

> **Haven**
>  h(E)aven
>  (tax) haven
>  haven (example [Milford Haven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milford_Haven))
>  h-AV-en

Answer (score 7):

First verse:

> ARK

Once raided by someone who sounds like five hundred,

> raiders of the lost ark - I guess Indy as a nickname for Dr Jones could also evoke the Indy 500

or something that crashed on Armenian highlands,

> Noah's Ark

like luminous city's triumphant landmark,

> Paris is the City of Light and has the Arc d'Triomphe

a 40's gun disjoined by queen saying "aah".

> That would be an ack-ack and the queen is non-rhotic so Ark comes out Ahk

Putting it all together:

> Ark Port Castle Haven

are all

> Places of refuge or safety?

Comment: rot13(Vaqvnancbyvf 500 & Vaqvnan Wbarf)?

Answer (score 6):

Second Verse:

> Port

Reasoning:

> Iberian grapes go through long fermenation, - Iberian wine is port, I think.
>  adapted in order to run on some system, - software can be ported
> so take a look north as the ship's sailing east, - if you face east and look north, you're looking to the left, i.e. the port side of the ship
> divide place in German by one million squared.  - not sure about this? Something to do with "Ort"?

Comment: last line - you found the correct base, and it has an SI prefix